# ValueError when coding quadratic formula

Tags: python, valueerror

I am coding the quadratic formula in Python. The following function is supposed to solve x^2-x-20. If you do the math you get -4 and 5.

```py
# Quadratic Formula
from math import sqrt
def findsolutions(a, b, c):
    """
    Find solutions to quadratic equations.
    """
    x1 = (-b + sqrt(b^2-4*a*c))/(2*a)
    x2 = (-b - sqrt(b^2-4*a*c))/(2*a)
    return x1, x2

x1, x2 = findsolutions(1,-1,-20)
print("The solutions to x^2-x-20 are", x1, "and", x2)
```

However, if you run it, you get:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Atharv 2020/Desktop/Python/1. Quadratic Formula.py", line 11, in <module>
    x1, x2 = findsolutions(1,-1,-20)
  File "C:/Users/Atharv 2020/Desktop/Python/1. Quadratic Formula.py", line 7, in findsolutions
    x1 = (-b + sqrt(b^2-4*a*c))/(2*a)
ValueError: math domain error
```

So what is going on?

Comment: looks like ```b^2-4*a*c``` is negative. and square root of negative numbers is complex

Comment: @Sujay It looks like you are right.

Edit: 4*1*(-20) is -80, and (-(-1))+(-(-80)) is just 1+80, or 81. `b^2-4*a*c` is positive.

Comment: FYI https://bbolker.github.io/math1mp/notes/random/r3_sqrtminusone.html

Comment: `**` is for power. For this case, I would recommend `b*b`

Answer (score 2):

In Python, `^` is a Bitwise operator called XOR (Exclusive-OR)

I think you've mistook it for calculating power. In python you calculate power using `**`.

> `x ** y` - x raised to the power y

So fix your code like this

> `x1 = (-b + sqrt(b**2-(4*a*c)))/(2*a)`

Comment: You missed the ```*```: ```x1 = (-b + sqrt(b**2-(4*a*c)))/(2*a)```

Comment: @Ram Thank you for this answer. I did confuse XOR with Power.

I could have used `math.pow()` but for this, I need to have written:
```from math import sqrt, pow```